# Query multiple rows with shared key field into single result row for every key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named **Form** with the following contents:

```
    FormType KeyField  Field   AlphaValue            NumericValue
    -------- --------- ------- --------------------  -------------
    A        AAA001    A001    EXT                   0.000000
    A        AAA001    A002    mail                  0.000000
    A        AAA001    A003                          190.000000
    A        AAA001    A004    example@example.com   0.000000
    A        ABC123    A001    DIST                  0.000000
    A        ABC123    A002    something             0.000000
    A        ABC123    A003                          215.000000
    A        BBB255    A002    delivery              0.000000
    A        BBB255    A003                          94.000000
    A        CCC923    A002    TECH                  0.000000
    A        DDD123    A004    mail@example.com      0.000000
```

The desired result needs to be the **KeyField** followed by every of the possible fields (in this case A001, A002, A003, A004), something like:

```
    TypeA   A001         A002         A003        A004
    ------- ------------ ------------ ----------- --------------------
    AAA001  EXT          mail         190.000000  example@example.com
    ABC123  DIST         something    215.000000
    BBB255               delivery     94.000000
    CCC923  TECH                      0.000000
    DDD123                            0.000000    mail@example.com
```

I've been working on this, but don't really reflect the desired result:

```
    select
    a.KeyField as 'TypeA',
    b.AlphaValue as 'A001',
    c.AlphaValue as 'A002', 
    d.NumericValue as 'A003', 
    e.AlphaValue as 'A004'
    from (select distinct KeyField from Form where FormType = 'A') as a,
    (select AlphaValue, KeyField from Form where FormType = 'A' and Field = 'A001') as b,
    (select AlphaValue, KeyField from Form where FormType = 'A' and Field = 'A002') as c,
    (select NumericValue, KeyField from Form where FormType = 'A' and Field = 'A003') as d,
    (select AlphaValue, KeyField from Form where FormType = 'A' and Field = 'A004') as e
    where 
    b.KeyField = a.KeyField 
    and c.KeyField = a.KeyField 
    and d.KeyField = a.KeyField 
    and e.KeyField = a.KeyField
```

The previous query result in:

```
    TypeA   A001         A002         A003        A004
    ------- ------------ ------------ ----------- --------------------
    AAA001  EXT          mail         190.000000  example@example.com
```

It just skip all keys that don't have a result for every of the required fields, when I need that the required fields that don't have a match to be replaced with empty string or 0.000000.

Any ideas on how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You need to learn how to use joins instead of comma separated queries. The way you have this coded is inner joins to each and every one of your queries. This is a real problem when you data structures using the EAV pattern.

Comment: If you can post your sample as something readily consumable I can help you build a query to get your data out of this. This article is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    master.KeyField AS 'TypeA',
    ISNULL(A001.AlphaValue, '') AS 'A001',
    ISNULL(A002.AlphaValue, '') AS 'A002', 
    ISNULL(A003.NumericValue, 0) AS 'A003', 
    ISNULL(A004.AlphaValue, '') AS 'A004'
FROM (
    SELECT FormType, KeyField
    FROM Form
    WHERE FormType = 'A'
    GROUP BY FormType, KeyField
) AS master
LEFT JOIN Form AS A001 
    ON master.FormType = A001.FormType AND master.KeyField = A001.KeyField AND A001.Field = 'A001'
LEFT JOIN Form AS A002 
    ON master.FormType = A002.FormType AND master.KeyField = A002.KeyField AND A002.Field = 'A002'
LEFT JOIN Form AS A003 
    ON master.FormType = A003.FormType AND master.KeyField = A003.KeyField AND A003.Field = 'A003'
LEFT JOIN Form AS A004 
    ON master.FormType = A004.FormType AND master.KeyField = A004.KeyField AND A004.Field = 'A004'
```

Basically we are querying the unique keys and then left joining all other fields. ISNULL function provides default values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing an aggregation anyway (which is what `distinct` essentially does), then you might as well use conditional aggregation:

```
select KeyField,
       max(case when keyfield = 'A001' then alphafield else '' end) as A001,
       max(case when keyfield = 'A002' then alphafield else '' end) as A002,
       max(case when keyfield = 'A003' then NumericValue else 0 end) as A003,
       max(case when keyfield = 'A004' then alphafield else ''end) as A004
from Form
where FormType = 'A'
group by KeyField;
```

This assumes that there is only one value for each of the keys (as implied by the question).

Comment: Good hack with max :) But you need to add GROUP BY clause